# Liberty Profile 8.5.5 WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.isUserInRole error

Tags: java, security, httprequest, httpresponse, websphere-liberty

I have a problem using Liberty Profile 8.5.5 with LDAP.
I have an **EAR with application.xml** setted correctly for security.
into the ear i have a **web probject with web.xml** setted correctly.
The login authentication goes well (`request.getRemoteUser()` gives correct result) but in the next action, when i use `response.isUserInRoles` returns me this exception:

> [FATAL] [isUserInRole - WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.java:327] Exception in method ...
>   Exception type: class java.lang.NullPointerException Msg: null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I really don't understand how this could happen...
If someone have a solution, a work-around, a fix, please tell me.

Comment: Hi, Just a note that this question was posted to the WASdev forum where it was suggested that a PMR should be raised against IBM. This appears to have been done.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I faced the exact same problem you're describing here. I am using WebSphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5.1 with Eclipse Kepler. My project uses the [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) 
framework, so in my web.xml I had the Wicket filter, like so:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>wicket.filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
        <param-value>my.wicket.Application</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>configuration</param-name>
        <param-value>deployment</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>wicket.filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

While debugging I found out that inside the isUserInRole function, WebSphere seemed to be looking for a servlet. Obviously, I wasn't using any servlets in my application, just the Wicket filter. So my workaround was to use the Wicket servlet in stead of the filter and that seems to work fine.

Long story short: Seems like isUserInRole doesn't work on WebSphere Liberty Profile when your application doesn't have any servlets.